# Programación estructurada Switch

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Escoge {
public static void main(String[] args) {

String[][] matriz = new String[2][5];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println ("Elige que quieres ingresar primero: frutas o nombres" );

String respuesta= scan.nextLine ();
switch (respuesta){

case "nombres":
System.out.println("Introduzca 5 nombres");
 for (int ix = 0; ix < matriz[0].length; ix++) {
 matriz[0][ix] = scan.nextLine();}
System.out.println("introduce 5 frutas");
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matriz[1].length; i1++) {   
 matriz[1][i1] = scan.nextLine();}
break;

case "frutas" : {
System.out.println("introduce 5 frutas");
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matriz[1].length; i1++) {   
            matriz[1][i1] = scan.nextLine();}             
 System.out.println("Introduzca 5 nombres");
 for (int ix = 0; ix < matriz[0].length; ix++) {
            matriz[0][ix] = scan.nextLine();}


Scanner ber = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Te muestro los nombres o las frutas?");    
String contesta = scan.nextLine();                                                                                             
switch (contesta) {                                            

case "nombres":                                                 
System.out.println("Los nombres son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[0]));             
System.out.println("Las frutas son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[1]));             
 break;                                                  
                                                                                 case "frutas":                                                  System.out.println("Las frutas son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[1]));             
System.out.println("Los nombres son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[0]));                
}}}}}
```

Mi pregunta es  : ¿Qué puedo agregar y en donde, algo para que me ayude a ejecutar completamente el caso `"nombres"`, es decir que  después de escribir los nombres y frutas continué preguntándome que quiere que imprima primero?
*(como el de frutas, ese si ejecuta completamente)*

Comment: El de frutas se ejecuta por que no pusiste un break despues del case, desde el segundo Scanner debe estar afuera del Switch

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan algunos `break;`  y además el nuevo `Scanner` que creas no tiene ninguna utilidad (me refiero a este `Scanner ber = new Scanner(System.in);`.

Aquí tienes el bloque de código con esos detalles corregidos:

```
    String[][] matriz = new String[2][5];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Elige que quieres ingresar primero: frutas o nombres");

    String respuesta = scan.nextLine();
    switch (respuesta) {

        case "nombres":
            System.out.println("Introduzca 5 nombres");
            for (int ix = 0; ix < matriz[0].length; ix++) {
                matriz[0][ix] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("introduce 5 frutas");
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matriz[1].length; i1++) {
                matriz[1][i1] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            break;

        case "frutas":
            System.out.println("introduce 5 frutas");
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matriz[1].length; i1++) {
                matriz[1][i1] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("Introduzca 5 nombres");
            for (int ix = 0; ix < matriz[0].length; ix++) {
                matriz[0][ix] = scan.nextLine();
            }
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Te muestro los nombres o las frutas?");
    String contesta = scan.nextLine();
    switch (contesta) {

        case "nombres":
            System.out.println("Los nombres son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[0]));
            System.out.println("Las frutas son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[1]));
            break;
        case "frutas":
            System.out.println("Las frutas son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[1]));
            System.out.println("Los nombres son" + Arrays.toString(matriz[0]));
            break;
    }
```

#### Out

```
debug:
Elige que quieres ingresar primero: frutas o nombres
frutas
introduce 5 frutas
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
Introduzca 5 nombres
n1
n2
n3
n4
n5
Te muestro los nombres o las frutas?
frutas
Las frutas son[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
Los nombres son[n1, n2, n3, n4, n5]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 28 seconds)
```